# How to reverse the sorting order (ascending-first) of a column in ng-table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

When I click a sortable column title it first sorts descending and on second click it's ascending. How can I reverse that?

I'm aware that you can set initial sorting order in settings, but I need to change default behavior of clicking on columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to configure ng-table in order to set ascending order first without changing the source code.

In [ngTableSorterRowController.js](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/blob/master/src/scripts/ngTableSorterRowController.js) you can read this:

```
var defaultSort = $scope.params.settings().defaultSort;
var inverseSort = (defaultSort === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc');
var sorting = $scope.params.sorting() && $scope.params.sorting()[parsedSortable] && ($scope.params.sorting()[parsedSortable] === defaultSort);
var sortingParams = (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) ? $scope.params.sorting() : {};
            sortingParams[parsedSortable] = (sorting ? inverseSort : defaultSort);
            $scope.params.parameters({
                sorting: sortingParams
            });
```

I think that `(sorting ? inverseSort : defaultSort);` is the code responsible of the ascending-first ordering behavior.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

After you create the table and set your tableParams variable, you can then use the settings method to set the default sort:

```
this.tableParams.settings({defaultSort: 'asc'});
```